# Exchange EWS Connectivity Issues

Tags: windows, powershell, exchange-server

I've inherited an Exchange 2007 SBS server and my client wants to migrate to Google Apps. So, in working to get the migration setup and use Google's tools, I'm trying to get the EWS service to work so I can just use Google's Server Migration Tool.  I've gone through pretty much every tutorial and set things up following the instructions:

```
 [PS] C:\Windows\system32>Set-WebServicesVirtualDirectory -Identity "THESERVER\EWS (SBS Web Applications)" -InternalUrl: https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

 [PS] C:\Windows\system32>Set-WebServicesVirtualDirectory -Identity "THESERVER\EWS (SBS Web Applications)" -ExternalUrl: https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

I then verified the settings with:

```
 [PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory |fl identity,internalurl,externalurl


 Identity    : THESERVER\EWS (SBS Web Applications)
 InternalUrl : https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
 ExternalUrl : https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

When I try to browse to the URL above internally and externally I just get a blank page, no errors or anything.

I also ran the `Test-OutlookWebServices | fl` command, here is the output:

```html
Id      : 1003
Type    : Information
Message : About to test AutoDiscover with the e-mail address admin@mydomain.com.

Id      : 1007
Type    : Information
Message : Testing server THESERVER.mydomain.local with the published name
           https://remote/EWS/Exchange.asmx & https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx.

Id      : 1019
Type    : Information
Message : Found a valid AutoDiscover service connection point. The AutoDiscover URL on this object is https://remote.mydomain.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

Id      : 1006
Type    : Information
Message : The Autodiscover service was contacted at https://remote.mydomain.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

Id      : 1013
Type    : Error
Message : When contacting https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx received the error The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

Id      : 1016
Type    : Error
Message : [EXCH]-Error when contacting the AS service at https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 225 milliseconds.

Id      : 1015
Type    : Success
Message : [EXCH]-Successfully contacted the OAB service at https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 0 milliseconds.

Id      : 1014
Type    : Success
Message : [EXCH]-Successfully contacted the UM service at https://sites/UnifiedMessaging/Service.asmx. The elapsed time was 18 milliseconds.

Id      : 1013
Type    : Error
Message : When contacting https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx received the error The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

Id      : 1016
Type    : Error
Message : [EXPR]-Error when contacting the AS service at https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 226 milliseconds.

Id      : 1015
Type    : Success
Message : [EXPR]-Successfully contacted the OAB service at https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 0 milliseconds.

Id      : 1014
Type    : Information
Message : [EXPR]-The UM is not configured for this user.

Id      : 1013
Type    : Error
Message : When contacting https://remote.mydomain.com/Rpc received the error The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Id      : 1017
Type    : Error
Message : [EXPR]-Error when contacting the RPC/HTTP service at https://remote.mydomain.com/Rpc. The elapsed time was 232 milliseconds.

Id      : 1006
Type    : Success
Message : The Autodiscover service was tested successfully.

Id      : 1021
Type    : Information
Message : The following web services generated errors.
              As in EXCH
              As, in EXPR
              Contacting server in EXPR
          Please use the prior output to diagnose and correct the errors.
```

So, being horrible at Windows (I'm a Linux guy), some things that stand out to me which I can't explain or figure out:

1. For some reason, one of the tests is trying to connect to `https://sites....` which won't resolve to anything, assuming the `Set-WebServicesVirtualDirectory` command actually did what the output said it did.
2. I would expect to get a 403 Error when trying to browse to `https://remote.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`, but I'm just getting a blank page.

I also tried [Microsoft's connectivity tester](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com) and am getting the following when testing the "Exchange Web Services synchronization, notification, availability, and Automatic Replies" which I'm hoping is related to the errors I'm getting.

[image]

So, what am I missing here?